# Center aligned paragraph on top of left aligned paragraph

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have:

```
<p align="center">Title</p>
<p>Body</p>
```

How can I make it so there is no line space between "Title" and "Body" ?

Comment: margin: 0 will most likely work, you can add padding:0 and line-height:1em to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p align="center" style="margin:0;">Title</p>
<p style="margin:0;">Body</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a margin to the paragraph:

```
<p style="text-align:center; margin: 0;">Title</p>
<p>Body</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most HTML elements have innate styles attached to them.

Try adding a css class to both of them and setting the style to margin:0;padding:0; to remove any space between the elements.